# MUI Autocomplete freeSolo not clearing input when using custom key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a multiline select by using MUI's `<Autocomplete/>`.

I want to use the `Tab` to submit the value and `Enter` to insert a newline.

Everything works as expected besides clearing the previously inputted value.

When I hit `Tab` the new chip appears but the string I wrote in the TextField doesn't disappear.

I have tried to clear the input using the event or refs in the keydown handler
e.g. `event.target.value = ''` or `ref.current.value=''` but to no avail.

Funnily enough I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-keydown-override-forked-h246k6?file=/demo.js) that works albeit on an older MUI version.

I have tried to copy 1:1 the code from the sandbox into my app but it it's not working.

Below is the actual component I'm trying to fix:

```
import { Chip } from "@mui/material"
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete"
import { useController, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form"

import { StyledInput } from "@/components/reusable/Input/StyledInput"

const AddSelectOptions = ({ name = "selectedItems" }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext()

  const { field } = useController({
    control,
    name,
    rules: {
      required: "Pole nie może być puste",
    },
  })
  const { onChange, value } = field
  const handleKeyDown = event => {
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Enter": {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.target.value += '\n';
        break;
      }
      case "Tab": {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (event.target.value !== '') {
          onChange([...value, event.target.value]);
        }
        break;

      }
      default:
    }
  }

  return (
    <Autocomplete<string, true, true, true>
      renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
        tagValue.map((text, index) => {
          return (
            <Chip
              size="small"
              key={text}
              label={text}
              {...getTagProps({ index })}
            />
          )
        })
      }
      multiple
      freeSolo
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        onChange(newValue)
      }}
      value={value}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        params.inputProps.onKeyDown = handleKeyDown
        return (
          <StyledInput
            {...params}
            label="Lista opcji*"
            name="select-options-temp-input"
            helperText=""
            placeholder="Zapisz nową opcję i zatwierdź [Tab]"
            multiline
          />
        )
      }}
      options={[]}
    />
  )
}

export default AddSelectOptions
```

The version of MUI I have is:

```
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.80",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.1",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.8",
    "material-ui-confirm": "^3.0.7",
```

I suspect that this is happening because of Autocomplete's `onChange` not triggering, yet I don't know how to trigger it by using `Tab`.

When not using `freeSolo` it works as expected but the input renders an arrow and an empty options list which I don't want and there is no reasonable way to remove it.